# An Incidence problem

Tags: linear-algebra

Is this intuition true: If any $d+1$ points among $d+2$ given points in $\mathbb{R}^d$ lies on a hyperplane then all of them lies on a hyperplane?

Comment: It seems to be true in $\mathbb R^2$. Can you think of a proof in $\mathbb R^2$, for example? Then we can see how we can extend the thinking to $\mathbb R^d$.Note that a hyperplane in $\mathbb R^2$ is nothing but a line.

Comment: Yes: this is true: $d+1$ points uniquely determine a hyperplane

Comment: Yes! for $\mathbb{R}^2$ is an easy task.

Comment: Seems right to me, though I can't come up with a proof off the top of my head. I find your title a bit confusing; the term "incidence" doesn't seem to describe your problem.

Comment: Not any $d+1$ points uniquely determine a hyperplane!

Comment: @Crostul That is not necessarily true; with $d+1$ points there could be no hyperplane passing through them, and there are cases where there are infinitely many.

Comment: @Sambo Incidence is [exactly the word to use](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incidence_geometry).

Comment: Acctually for $d=2$, we can replace $d+2$ by any natural number $n$ by using Sylvester-Gallai Theorem

Comment: @123... Subtract the first point from all the others, just to talk about subspaces. Then consider a maximal subset that is linearly independent among the other $d+1$ points. The subspace generated by them will have dimension $<d$, because any $d+1$ of them are in a hyperplane. Therefore, all the points are in the subspace generated by them and that subspace is inside a hyperplane, since it has dimension $<d$.

Comment: @minghan But when you add the first point (the one which you subtract) may increase the dimension in final step

Comment: @123... I meant subtraction as in component-wise difference, using the addition in the usual vector space structure in $\mathbb{R}^d$. Not removing the point. If you have found a subspace containing all the points, and then add (the vector space addition) a vector to all the points, the subspace gets translated to a hyperplane, not necessarily passing through the origin.

Comment: I don't think it changes the dimension @123... I think minghan is suggesting an affine translation, considering a linear subspace the linear span of these points belongs to, and then affine translating back, which is equivalent to finding a hyperplane the affine span of these points belongs to

Comment: Interesting exercise: Can you come up with a proof by contradiction?  Obviously, if there isn't a hyperplane that contains all $d+2$ points, then there must be a point you can select that doesn't lie in the hyperplane spanned by the other $d+1$ points (those $d+1$ other points must obviously fall in the same hyperplane).  What can you make of that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $P = \{x_1,...,x_{d+2} \} \subset \mathbb{R}^{d}$.

Let $\delta = \dim \operatorname{aff} P$. (This is the dimension of the affine hull of $P$, which is the dimension of the smallest linear subspace that contains some translate of $P$.) Note that $\delta \le d$.

I claim that $\delta \le d-1$. Suppose $\delta = d$ to obtain a contradiction. Then
there is an affine basis $B \subset P$ with $|B| = d+1$. However, by assumption,
there is a hyperplane containing $B$, and hence $|B| $ is not affinely
independent which is a contradiction.

Hence there is a hyperplane containing $P$.

**Addendum**:

This can all be expressed in the context of linear spaces.
Note that $y_1,...,y_k \in \mathbb{R}^d$ lie on a hyperplane **iff** $\dim \operatorname{sp} \{y_i-y_1\}_{i=2}^k \le d-1$.

Now suppose $x_1,...,x_{d+2}$ are **not** contained in some hyperplane. Then we must have $\dim \operatorname{sp} \{x_i-x_1\}_{i=2}^{d+2} = d$. In particular, $x_2-x_1,...,x_{d+1}-x_1$ contains a basis and so
there we can choose $d$ of them (let the indices be $I \subset \{2,...,d+2\}$, with $|I| = d$) such that $x_i-x_1$, $i \in I$ form a basis. Since they form a basis, the points $x_1, x_i$, $i \in I$ cannot be contained in a hyperplane, which
contradicts the original assumption. Hence the points are contained in some subspace.